# How do I get a hacker out of my phone?

Tags: security

The other day my phone number was added to my Google account, data was turned on and off. Different things have been happening. I have a LG V35 and it has an LG VPN section and when I check the log. It shows background scripts or whatever being run in my phone. I do not have a VPN. I tried resetting my phone to factory and it didn't work. Please someone help me get this person out of my phone. The other day it said it got one profile.

[image]

Comment: Its the log from the app itself. I dont think its from some hacker.
What other problems are you having that suggest it is hacker?

Comment: My Google phone number being added to my Google account. Me having to toggle my data on and off like somebody battling over a light switch.

Comment: imagine i would give you full remote access via USB debugging on my phone. what exactly would you do if you were the "hacker"? btw you would need root access for a backdoor, and for this you need physical access to my device at least once. And why should a 'hacker' switch off internet connection when this is the only way for remote access? You are really not that interesting..

Comment: @alecxs agreed. This looks over-consciousness without evidence. Or may be the issues are something else.

Comment: My phone is not rooted. I have no VPN. A guy did have physical access to my phone and messed around with developer options and what not. He was telling me how he could hack into people's Wi-Fi and all kinds of shit.

Comment: @Chrissorey you shouldn't be that helpless. Device is yours, in your hands, no one can control it better than you. A Factory Reset returns the device to its original state. Any modifications made by user are reversed except if the device was rooted and partitions other than `/data` and `/cache` e.g. `/system` or `/vendor` were modified. But that doesn't seems to be the case with your device. Another (minor) possibility is to take control of device at kernel or bootloader level e.g. through rootkits. But isn't possible by just making a few changes in Developer Options or so. That needs hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your installed app (in settings). Is there some new weird app you have never seen before and not installed yourself which is labeled as "System-App"? Yes? Your are screwed. Only way to get rid of it is to re-flash the whole ROM. Well you could also root your phone and use one of countless apps/modules to remove System-Apps. But God knows what the virus will do when it gets root access. 
I have seen this years ago on a Huawei Mate 1. The app was turning on WiFi and Data permanently to load ads and malware. Factory reset did nothing. Clean flash of a new ROM was the only way.